# How do I read in lines from a text file and search through all rows and tables in a database for matching strings?

Tags: python, sqlite

My project involves using Python to extract forensic data from a Windows image file.  I have now written programs that carry out the extraction and saved the data to a SQLite Database for analysis.  I have a keyword text file that I would like to read in line by line and search all the tables in my database for the strings but I'm having problems carrying this out.  I have managed to read all my rows from all the tables in the database but I don't know how to search for the strings that are in my text file and see if they are in any of the rows.
Can someone please advise?  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
condition = ' OR '.join(["field LIKE ?" for k in keywords])
sql = "SELECT * FROM {t} WHERE {c}".format(c=condition, t=tablename)
args = ['%{k}%'.format(k=k) for k in keywords]
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give it a go.  I'm not really a programmer so this is all new to me!

Comment: I had to change it slightly to be able to select all tables. I replaced tablename with {t}.format(t=table) but I'm getting syntax errors because my quotes are not in the right place.  How do I write "SELECT * from {t}.format(t=table WHERE {c}".  Thanks again!

Comment: I've edited the code above to allow the `tablename` to be specified by a variable.